# Sort and extract values in a nested list

Tags: list-manipulation, sorting, peak-detection

I want to sort the following nested list of peak points by the y values while keeping the dimensions consistent.

I then want to extract the x value of the largest and second largest y values (if the dimension is 1 then the only item of the list should be the largest but I would also like to extract it as one of the second largest group too).

Any help is greatly appreciated!

````
listOfPeaks = {{{1050, 0.0181119}, {1281, 0.023783}, {1773, 
     0.32029}, {2035, 0.0233451}, {2167, 0.0159332}}, {{1053, 
     0.0173196}, {1282, 0.0229119}, {1773, 0.326619}, {2033, 
     0.022375}, {2165, 0.0152391}}, {{1056, 0.0166205}, {1283, 
     0.0221355}, {1773, 0.332107}, {2032, 0.021521}, {2164, 
     0.0146316}}, {{1058, 0.0159982}, {1284, 0.0214385}, {1772, 
     0.336923}, {2031, 0.0207607}, {2162, 0.014094}}, {{1061, 
     0.0154399}, {1285, 0.0208085}, {1772, 0.341195}, {2030, 
     0.020078}, {2160, 0.0136136}}, {{1063, 0.0149354}, {1286, 
     0.0202355}, {1772, 0.345011}, {2030, 0.0194612}, {2159, 
     0.013181}}, {{1065, 0.0144767}, {1287, 0.0197113}, {1772, 
     0.348445}, {2029, 0.0188999}, {2158, 0.0127885}}, {{1067, 
     0.0140573}, {1288, 0.0192295}, {1772, 0.351557}, {2028, 
     0.0183859}, {2156, 0.0124305}}, {{1069, 0.0136721}, {1288, 
     0.0187846}, {1772, 0.354392}, {2027, 0.0179127}, {2155, 
     0.012102}}, {{1070, 0.0133166}, {1289, 0.0183724}, {1772, 
     0.356988}, {2027, 0.0174762}, {2154, 0.0117991}}, {{1072, 
     0.0129872}, {1290, 0.0179887}, {1771, 0.359379}, {2026, 
     0.017071}, {2153, 0.0115187}}, {{1073, 0.0126809}, {1290, 
     0.0176304}, {1771, 0.361589}, {2026, 0.0166932}, {2152, 
     0.0112581}}, {{1075, 0.0123953}, {1291, 0.0172952}, {1771, 
     0.363639}, {2025, 0.0163411}, {2150, 0.0110151}}, {{1076, 
     0.0121279}, {1292, 0.01698}, {1771, 0.365546}, {2025, 
     0.0160102}, {2149, 0.0107877}}, {{1078, 0.011877}, {1292, 
     0.0166836}, {1771, 0.367326}, {2024, 0.0157005}, {2149, 
     0.0105743}}, {{1079, 0.011641}, {1293, 0.0164036}, {1771, 
     0.368993}, {2024, 0.0154075}, {2148, 0.0103737}}, {{1080, 
     0.0114185}, {1293, 0.016139}, {1771, 0.370557}, {2023, 
     0.0151321}, {2147, 0.0101844}}, {{1081, 0.0112081}, {1294, 
     0.015888}, {1771, 0.372028}, {2023, 0.0148706}, {2146, 
     0.0100055}}, {{1082, 0.011009}, {1294, 0.0156499}, {1771, 
     0.373416}, {2022, 0.0146232}}, {{1084, 0.01082}, {1295, 
     0.015423}, {1771, 0.374727}, {2022, 0.0143881}}, {{1085, 
     0.0106404}, {1295, 0.0152073}, {1770, 0.375969}, {2021, 
     0.0141639}}, {{1086, 0.0104695}, {1295, 0.015001}, {1770, 
     0.377149}, {2021, 0.0139511}}, {{1087, 0.0103065}, {1296, 
     0.0148042}, {1770, 0.378271}, {2021, 0.0137472}}, {{1088, 
     0.0101508}, {1296, 0.0146157}, {1770, 0.379338}, {2020, 
     0.0135526}}, {{1089, 0.010002}, {1297, 0.014435}, {1770, 
     0.380355}, {2020, 0.0133666}}, {{1297, 0.0142619}, {1770, 
     0.381326}, {2020, 0.0131879}}, {{1297, 0.0140953}, {1770, 
     0.382253}, {2019, 0.0130165}}, {{1298, 0.0139352}, {1770, 
     0.383141}, {2019, 0.0128523}}, {{1298, 0.0137813}, {1770, 
     0.383992}, {2019, 0.012694}}, {{1298, 0.0136328}, {1770, 
     0.384808}, {2018, 0.0125413}}, {{1299, 0.0134895}, {1770, 
     0.385592}, {2018, 0.012395}}, {{1299, 0.0133515}, {1770, 
     0.386345}, {2018, 0.0122535}}, {{1299, 0.013218}, {1770, 
     0.387069}, {2018, 0.0121166}}, {{1299, 0.0130888}, {1770, 
     0.387767}, {2017, 0.0119846}}, {{1300, 0.012964}, {1770, 
     0.38844}, {2017, 0.0118573}}, {{1300, 0.0128431}, {1770, 
     0.389089}, {2017, 0.0117339}}, {{1300, 0.0127259}, {1770, 
     0.389715}, {2017, 0.0116141}}, {{1301, 0.0126121}, {1770, 
     0.39032}, {2016, 0.0114981}}, {{1301, 0.012502}, {1769, 
     0.390906}, {2016, 0.0113861}}, {{1301, 0.0123951}, {1769, 
     0.391474}, {2016, 0.0112773}}, {{1301, 0.012291}, {1769, 
     0.392024}, {2016, 0.0111714}}, {{1301, 0.0121898}, {1769, 
     0.392557}, {2016, 0.0110683}}, {{1302, 0.0120917}, {1769, 
     0.393073}, {2015, 0.0109687}}, {{1302, 0.0119961}, {1769, 
     0.393574}, {2015, 0.0108718}}, {{1302, 0.011903}, {1769, 
     0.39406}, {2015, 0.0107774}}, {{1302, 0.0118122}, {1769, 
     0.394532}, {2015, 0.0106853}}, {{1303, 0.0117238}, {1769, 
     0.394991}, {2015, 0.0105955}}, {{1303, 0.0116378}, {1769, 
     0.395437}, {2014, 0.0105083}}, {{1303, 0.0115538}, {1769, 
     0.395871}, {2014, 0.0104235}}, {{1303, 0.0114718}, {1769, 
     0.396294}, {2014, 0.0103407}}, {{1303, 0.0113916}, {1769, 
     0.396705}, {2014, 0.0102597}}, {{1304, 0.0113135}, {1769, 
     0.397105}, {2014, 0.0101805}}, {{1304, 0.0112372}, {1769, 
     0.397495}, {2013, 0.0101031}}, {{1304, 0.0111627}, {1769, 
     0.397876}, {2013, 0.0100281}}, {{1304, 0.0110897}, {1769, 
     0.398247}}, {{1304, 0.0110183}, {1769, 0.398609}}, {{1305, 
     0.0109484}, {1769, 0.398962}}, {{1305, 0.0108802}, {1769, 
     0.399307}}, {{1305, 0.0108134}, {1769, 0.399644}}, {{1305, 
     0.010748}, {1769, 0.399973}}, {{1305, 0.0106838}, {1769, 
     0.400295}}, {{1305, 0.0106209}, {1769, 0.40061}}, {{1306, 
     0.0105592}, {1769, 0.400917}}, {{1306, 0.0104989}, {1769, 
     0.401219}}, {{1306, 0.0104398}, {1769, 0.401513}}, {{1306, 
     0.0103817}, {1769, 0.401802}}, {{1306, 0.0103247}, {1769, 
     0.402084}}, {{1306, 0.0102688}, {1769, 0.402361}}, {{1306, 
     0.0102138}, {1769, 0.402632}}, {{1307, 0.0101599}, {1769, 
     0.402897}}, {{1307, 0.010107}, {1769, 0.403158}}, {{1307, 
     0.0100551}, {1768, 0.403414}}, {{1307, 0.010004}, {1768, 
     0.403665}}, {{1768, 0.403911}}, {{1768, 0.404153}}, {{1768, 
     0.40439}}, {{1768, 0.404623}}, {{1768, 0.404852}}, {{1768, 
     0.405077}}, {{1768, 0.405297}}, {{1768, 0.405514}}, {{1768, 
     0.405727}}, {{1768, 0.405937}}, {{1768, 0.406143}}, {{1768, 
     0.406345}}, {{1768, 0.406544}}, {{1768, 0.40674}}, {{1768, 
     0.406932}}, {{1768, 0.407122}}, {{1768, 0.407308}}, {{1768, 
     0.407492}}};

Map[Length, listOfPeaks, {1}]

```
````

Answer (score 3):

If I understood correctly:

```
tab = SortBy[#, Last] & /@ listOfPeaks
Table[If[Length@t == 1, {t[[-1]], t[[-1]]}, {t[[-1]], t[[-2]]}], {t, tab}]
```

First it sorts each sublist by the last element (the $y$ value), then it iterates and pick twice the last element if the element is a `List` of length 1, or the two lasts otherwise.

Comment: Thanks for your help, this is what I was looking for!